# Fourier transform of trigonometric function

Tags: fourier-transform

I would like to ask for some help on the Fourier transform of the following function.

$F(t)=\frac{cos(\Omega t)}{(\lambda^2+t^2)}$

I can do the Fourier transformation with the cosine function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it Fourier series  (as in your title) or Fourier transform (as I believe it is) ?

Comment: Oh, it is Fourier transform, I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

I will here define the Fourier transform by
$$
\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \, e^{-i\omega t} \, dt
$$

Rewriting $\cos \Omega t$ as $\frac12(e^{i\Omega t}+e^{-i\Omega t})$ gives
$$
\hat{F}(\omega) 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\Omega t)}{\lambda^2+t^2} \, e^{-i\omega t} \, dt
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\frac12(e^{i\Omega t}+e^{-i\Omega t})}{\lambda^2+t^2} \, e^{-i\omega t} \, dt
= \frac12 \left( 
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda^2+t^2} \, e^{-i(\omega-\Omega)t}
+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda^2+t^2} \, e^{-i(\omega+\Omega)t}
\right) \\
= \frac12 \left( \hat{G}(\omega-\Omega) + \hat{G}(\omega+\Omega) \right)
,
$$
where
$$
G(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2+t^2}
.
$$

Can you calculate the Fourier transform of $G$?